# Can a husband be expecting?

Tags: word-choice

It's common to say that a pregnant woman is expecting, but is it acceptable to say that her husband is expecting? I ask because my male teacher's wife is expecting in a week.

In case you didn't know, to be expecting means (for a pregnant woman, at least) that one will be giving birth soon, but it could generalize to males as meaning "will have a new child soon."

Comment: [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expecting) doesn't broaden beyond pregnant.

Comment: Despite what @Edwin correctly notes, if it was clear you were talking about a man people would understand you were using figurative language, so long as the rest of your language use was competent.

Comment: ... To be fair, I've heard the broadening 'We're expecting'. But I'd consider a father-to-be's use of 'I'm expecting' to be wry, self-centred, or weird.

Comment: Could be valid, if the father-to-be realizes that he should expect sleepless nights, constant worry, enormous college tuition bills, and eventual disappointment in conjunction with the likely disgrace of his family name.

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth. I think it's perfectly fine to say a mother or couple is expecting, eg. "They are expecting their third child in the spring." "She is expecting a new baby any day now." But not the daddy. I am already a bit creeped out by "We're trying to get pregnant." I guess it avoids saying in polite company, "I'm trying to get my wife pregnant."

Comment: Some of them may look as if they might be.

Comment: The term "expecting" is increasingly applied to the husband/father, though it has not quite passed over into "common" usage yet.

Comment: I've seen the phrase *pregnant mothers and expectant fathers*, which makes good sense in that context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["expecting a baby"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107141/expecting-a-baby) Maybe it's the case that these two questions, closely related but not identical, could be merged.

Comment: Also related:[A way of describing the lesbian parent that is not pregnant?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168957/a-way-of-describing-the-lesbian-parent-that-is-not-pregnant)

Answer (score 1):

The idiom for this is: **expectant father.**  However, if you were to say your teacher was expecting most people would assume the teacher to be female and pregnant.  Context is key here.

> An expectant ​mother/​father/​parent is someone whose ​child has not ​yet been ​born.
>
> [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/expectant)

Comment: So Id have to say that his wife is pregnant. Thanks!

Comment: Some clue as to gender is all that's needed.  And even then only to sate curiosity.  People eventually get curious about the gender for any character you describe.

Comment: @FarazMasroor  The following terms are also used: Father-to-be, and the more colloquial, Dad-to-be. Otherwise, I'd just say "my teacher is going to be a dad/father soon" No confusion there.